# Bug in reputation pages for self-accepted answers?

Tags: support, status-completed, reputation, accepted-answer

Obviously I know that I cannot vote on my questions or answers. In my `reputation` page, it shows votes given to my **answer**, but when I visit that post, I don't see any votes.

I notice that on the questions where I accepted my own answer, it shows as "2 Votes" in the reputation page for my question but **no reputation** is given. Why is such an unusual behavior there?

Is this  really a bug?

[image: Rep Page]

Here in the image above are two question answered by me only, but by mistake I had clicked on vote. Is it because of that I am getting 2 Votes on that question??

Comment: which of your questions?

Comment: It's really not clear what you mean. It would help if you could say exactly what you're seeing in the reputation tab, as well as why you think it's got anything to do with trying to vote on your own question.

Comment: It's not 100% clear (to me) what you're asking.  If you see votes in Reputation history with 0 value it means that you hit the rep cap for that day and didn't get any rep for that vote.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no bug here. The reputation page doesn't *only* show votes. Other actions that normally affect reputation such as suggesting edits or accepting answers will show up there as well.

So far today, you submitted two suggested edits that were approved. Each approved edit awarded you 2 reputation.

You also accepted two of your own answers. That showed up on your reputation activity page, but as you can see, there is no +X number beside those lines, so you did not get any reputation for that.

http://fhc.quickmediasolutions.com/image/-1758028080.png

As you can see in the screenshot, the first column shows you the reputation awarded (or taken away), the second column is the timestamp, and the third is the type of action that occurred. So, you have two edits and two accepts of your own answers for a total of +4 reputation.

---

The above is true for the "by time" view. "by post" shows a different picture that looks like it might, indeed, be a defect:

http://fhc.quickmediasolutions.com/image/-1758082147.png

Comment: see here: http://awesomescreenshot.com/064l0t8ed  I see the same issue as the OP

Comment: Look at the "by post" tab. The two accepts are showing up strangely there ("2 votes" each and no link to the question or answer)

Comment: @AManAPlanACanalPanama Interesting. I see that as well. You guys are looking at the "by post" view and my screenshot was from "by time". No idea why the two are different... that might be a bug, indeed.

Comment: @AnnaLear see OP's update -- it looks even weirder

Answer (score 4):

This isn't a bug really (as explained above), *but* I agree it is unintuitive (even though it is correct in terms of consistency).

Starting with the next build, we'll collapse self-accepts into a single event, since this is a much more intuitive view of things (and 2 events for no rep change that are in fact the same vote under the covers is just...weird).

Comment: So accepting an answer counts as a "vote"? Is that why the "by post" view shows "2 votes" instead of "accepted" in the third column on my screenshots?

Comment: @Anna - well, that's a matter of view I suppose, all "things" here are "votes" (they're actually stored in a Posts -> Votes table, we literally call them votes...so maybe our naming is biased from a developer view).  The "2 whatever" is really because there's *some* multiple votes/events being rolled up for that post, we chose to call that "whatever" votes.  I have no idea if that made sense, I hope it did!

Comment: Ahh... Overloaded terminology. Got it. :)